# Is it possible to see the error message from WPF crashing?

Tags: c#, wpf

When writing WPF application I often find that upon running new fucntions it will sometimes close, usually without an error message. This can make debugging challenging as I usually have to guess and experiment with the code to find the error. Is it possible to see the error messages (something like the error message of a console output), would it involve the output window?

Comment: Please [post code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows this “certain function”.

Comment: Use the debugger (F5). It will break on the line that throws the exception which crashes your application and display the exception message.

Comment: Thank you @BionicCode exactly what I was looking for! Sorry for the poor question.

Answer (score 4):

You can catch exception by adding `DispatcherUnhandledException` in `App.xaml`

```
<Application x:Class="Organizer.UI.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Organizer.UI"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
             Startup="Application_Startup"
             DispatcherUnhandledException="Application_DispatcherUnhandledException">
```

And when it create `Application_DispatcherUnhandledException` in `App.xaml.cs` you can show it like this

```
private void Application_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error" + Environment.NewLine + e.Exception.Message, "Error");
    e.Handled = true;
}
```